# how to write mysql 1 query sum price group by category and year?

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| CategoryP   | MinutesT            | DateTimeDo          |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       Sleep | 7777777             | 01-11-2015 19:32:44 |
|        Work | 1231232453465       | 01-12-2009 22:33:49 |
|         Eat | 55555               | 15-08-2020 22:08:24 |
|       Sleep | 23423421            | 02-01-2009 22:33:57 |
|        Work | 88888               | 23-01-2012 22:37:34 |
|         Eat | 789679657645        | 04-12-2002 15:23:49 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to output :

```
2002 : Eat(789679657645) : Sleep(0) : Work(0)
2009 : Eat(0) : Sleep(23423421) : Work(1231232453465)
2012 : Eat(0) : Sleep(0) : Work(88888)
2015 : Eat(0) : Sleep(7777777) : Work(0)
2020 : Eat(0) : Sleep(0) : Work(0)
```

Can do with 1 mysql query? I tried :

```
SELECT SUM(MinutesT) FROM table
GROUP BY Year(DateTimeDo), CategoryP
```

It show wrong output. Could anyone guide me?

Comment: What is the data type of `DateTimeDo`? Also do you want just 1 column with all the values concatenated separated by `:` in the results?

Comment: @forpas, data type is DateTime. Yes 1 column with all value separated by : result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with 2 levels of aggregation.
First cross join the distinct years to the distinct categories and left join to the table to aggregate and get the totals for each combination of year and category.
After that you must aggregate again only per year and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate all the totals:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
         year, 
         ' : ',
         GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT(CategoryP, '(', total, ')')
           ORDER BY CategoryP
           SEPARATOR ' : '
         )  
       ) result
FROM (
  SELECT y.year, c.CategoryP, COALESCE(SUM(MinutesT), 0) total 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DateTimeDo) year FROM tablename) y
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CategoryP FROM tablename) c
  LEFT JOIN tablename t 
  ON t.CategoryP = c.CategoryP AND YEAR(t.DateTimeDo) = y.year
  GROUP BY y.year, c.CategoryP
) t
GROUP BY year
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=327d9d8bb938b5f734be61bd39868209).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.